# Removable device shows 2 MB unallocated

Tags: partitioning

In the device list I can select `/dev/sda` (HDD) and `/dev/sdb` (USB removable device).

It shows up with 2 MB size, which is smaller than the actual capacity of the device.

[Gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLDvR.png)

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 2 MiB, 2097152 bytes, 4096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1697c862    

# parted /dev/sdb print free
Model: Kingston DT 101 G2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2097kB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type  File system  Flags
        32,3kB  2097kB  2065kB        Free Space
```

Comment: What is that "removable USB device"? It may be relevant.

Comment: Can you show what do `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and `sudo parted /dev/sdb print free` say?

Comment: @AlexP OK, I've added them to the question

Comment: Have you tried to remove all partitions and create a new big partition?

Comment: @Saibot there is just this 2 MB unallocated space, nothing to remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a hardware failure. There is nothing on the software side you can do.

I have a thumb drive which once behaved like this. I was able to make it work, again, by opening it, taking the 2 parts it consisted of apart, and sticking them back together, again. It still had its data on it but I nuked it, just to be sure it's not corrupted. That is, I created a new partition table and a new partition in it. But you could also copy the existing data back onto a more stable drive if you need it (and just hope it's not corrupted).

That is of course not to say it will work for your thumb drive. Furthermore, I wouldn't exactly rely on a drive which failed in the past to work in the future.